# ios: String to Date conversion

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to convert my date from NSString to NSDate using following code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateformatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

currMonth = 3;
currYear = 2012;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/%2d/%d", currMonth, currYear];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"0"];
myDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"myStr: %@",str);
NSLog(@"myMonth: %2d",currMonth);
NSLog(@"myYear: %d",currYear);
NSLog(@"myDate: %@",myDate);
```

Above code is giving me wrong date. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which date will be given? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your output? Keep in mind, that NSDate is in UTC.

`2012-03-01 00:00:00 (GMT+1)` is `2012-02-39 23:00:00 (UTC)`

Another tip:

`%02` formats your integers with leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I get following output myStr: 01/03/2012
myMonth:  3
myYear: 2012
myDate: 2012-02-29 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: As Christoph said, the NSDate objects stores the date in UTC, so when you get the object description using `NSLog(@"myDate: %@",myDate);` it will print in UTC. Try outputting the date using the formatter, i think the output you expect will appear once it is converted to your local timezone. Something like: `NSLog(@"myDate: %@", [dateformatter stringFromDate:myDate]);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string
{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSTimeInterval interval = 5 * 60 * 60;

NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:string];  
date1 = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
if(!date1) date1= [NSDate date];
[dateFormat release];
[locale release];

return date1;
}
```

Tell me if it helps u :]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateformatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

int currMonth = 3;
int currYear = 2012;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"01/%2d/%d", currMonth, currYear];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"0"];

//SET YOUT TIMEZONE HERE
dateformatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
myDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"myStr: %@",str);
NSLog(@"myMonth: %2d",currMonth);
NSLog(@"myYear: %d",currYear);
NSLog(@"myDate: %@",myDate);
```

Comment: this will give myDate: 2012-03-01 08:00:00 +0000